Why is the TPS2640 not working?

hi, why doesn't my tps2640 work...? I thought the SHDN pin didn't pull down and it didn't work by connecting it to the RTN pin, so I forced it to pull down using a jumper cord, but it didn't work. Is it a problem with the resistance light element value? What I want is 12V input, 12V output

You have pulled the SHDN pin low so the chip is in shutdown mode and it is not enabled.
You have also left the EP pin 17 unconnected, which is not what datasheet tells how to connect it.

The SHDN pin is actually ¬SHDN (note the overline); it needs to be pulled high, not low, to enable the chip. You've explicitly disabled it, so of course it isn't working.
Another obvious issue I see is this, on page 4 of the datasheet:

Your schematic marks the thermal pad as unconnected, which is contrary to datasheet recommendations.
